# Is it natural to say "No way did the team win" or "No way the team won"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

I am talking about the structure "**[(there is) no way](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/way_1#way_idmg_45)**"

> (informal) used to say that there is no possibility that you will do
> something or that something will happen
>
> ‘Do you want to help?’ ‘No way!’
>
> No way am I going to drive them there.
>
> There's no way we could afford that sort of money.

---

According to the dictionary, if we use "**No way**" at the beginning of a sentence, then we have to inverse the auxiliary verb and make it stand before the subject. However, if we use "**There is no way**", then we don't have to inverse the auxiliary verb.

For example, "**No way do I want to help you**" and "**There's no way I want to help you**".

However, some native speakers, which I asked, don't say that way.

Now, you think that team  can not win the match and when your friend says "**The team won**".

Is it natural to say "**No way did the team win**" or "**No way the team won**"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> According to the dictionary, if we use "No way" at the beginning of a sentence, then we have to inverse the auxiliary verb and make it stand before the subject.

Well, no, the dictionary you linked gives no guidance or rules about usage; it just *shows* a usage that does invert like that.* In fact, I would say that that inverted form is rather informal. Putting "no way" at the beginning of the sentence to begin with is too informal for academic writing, but "No way did they win" is slightly more colloquial than "No way they won." But both are in common usage.

* Please understand the ways and degrees that we can rely on dictionaries. The example sentences are there to illustrate, not to draw boundaries around usage. You [can't conclude](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/310213/do-we-have-the-structure-to-be-upset-with-somebody-for-doing-something-and-to), just because they don't give an example of a certain construction, that it's impossible.